# 127.0.0.1:8000 refused to connect after django manage.py runserver

Tags: python-3.x, django

I'm new to python and django. I did the

```
python manage.py runserver
```

in cmd for the first time and it showed starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/.
It said：

> System check identified no issues (o silenced)April 04，2023- 19:42:34
> Django version 2.2.4,using settings 'MyProject.settings!Starting development server at http://127.0.0.1:8000/Quit
>
> http://127.0.0.1:8000/Quit the server withCTRL-BREAK

But in chrome it said "this site cant be reached".
It said:

> ERR SSL PROTOCOL ERROR

my setting.py:

```
ALLOWED_HOSTS = ['*',]
```

Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: it ma also be caused because of the browser. can you change the browser and try running on firefox?

Comment: or maybe the site is not providing the secure ssl connection

Comment: You've not set up secure settings, which is fine for a new project - you're just setting things up. Seems like Chrome is objecting to this though - can you see a "proceed anyway" option on the Chrome error page? Also, in your settings, is `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` set at all?